# Можно ли заменить двоеточие многоточием? Прописные-строчные при переводе фамилии?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная

> Этот дом Голливуд избрал для проживания героини Джулии Робертс в
>   кинокартине «Ешь, молись, люби». И об этом доме существует городская
>   легенда. ***Она гласит: давным-давно в старом палаццо жила знатная
>   семья по фамилии Франжипани (Красный жасмин).*** Из далёких странствий
>   по миру хозяин привёз с собой большую обезьяну, которую для забавы
>   держали при дворе. Однажды, возвращаясь домой, глава семейства
>   издалека услышал, что из окон доносятся крики отчаянья и громкие
>   рыдания, а приблизившись, обнаружил, что дворец его окружает толпа,
>   которая указывает на высокую башню. С замиранием сердца поднял он
>   глаза и увидел, что домашняя любимица похитила его единственного
>   крохотного сына из колыбели и восседает теперь на самом краю кровли,
>   обхватив надежду семьи своими безобразными лапами.

Если я сделаю так:

*Она гласит... Давным-давно в старом палаццо жила знатная семья по фамилии Франжипани (красный жасмин),*

я очень промахнусь? О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редко отвечаю на вопросы по пунктуации, так как плохо в ней разбираюсь, но тут, мне кажется, дело не в этом.
1. Слово "гласить" имеет значение "сообщает, утверждает" и предполагает после себя или двоеточие и краткое в одно, зачастую закавыченное, утверждение, -

> Учение Реформированных церквей, присоединившихся к Аугсбургскому вероисповеданию, о таком словесном признании гласит: Никто не может знать своих грехов.

Или распространение, через союз "что", -

> Приказ гласил, что подполковнику Белову рекомендуется безотлагательно
>   прибыть в некий гренадерский полк, базирующийся сейчас в Польше.

То есть, рассказ легенды в один абзац не предполагает употребление данного глагола. По крайней мере без союза "что".

2. Фраза "Она гласит", здесь вообще лишняя и без нее можно вполне обойтись, -

> И об этом доме существует городская легенда: Давным-давно
>   в старом палаццо жила знатная семья по фамилии Франжипани (*красный
>   жасмин*).

Здесь, кстати, двоеточие не смущает, так как вторая часть предложения действительно поясняет первую.

Comment: Марк Из♦, всё неправильно, но идея правки мною слоцирована (от "локатор")... Убираем "она гласит" или заменяем глагол; двоеточие категорически невозможно; рисуем точку. Спасибо.

Comment: Как-то мне неуютно с таким порядком слов: "Об этом доме существует легенда". Если не хотите стандартного "Существует легенда об этом доме", тогда так: "Об этом доме **повествует** легенда"?

Answer (score 0):

Употребление многоточия в данном предложения будет грубой пунктуационной ошибкой.

Многоточие указывает на недосказанность, на неожиданный переход от одной мысли к другой, многоточие употребляется для указания на то, что приводимое перечисление неполное и могло бы быть продолжено.

В Вашем же тексте двоеточие указывает на пояснительно-разъяснительную функцию.

Comment: Сержик, пояснительно-разъяснительную функция возможна, если за двоеточием следует ***одно*** предложение. Два, через точку, - уже невозможно. А у меня - целый рассказ...

Comment: Двоеточие вводит одно предложение, которое заканчивается после скобок. Оно гласит (а именно).

Comment: Какую функцию здесь будет выполнять многоточие?

Comment: Мол, соберитесь с духом: сейчас последует подробное повествование.

Comment: Рассказ не заканчивается скобкой. ***И об этом доме существует городская легенда. Она гласит***: *давным-давно в старом палаццо жила знатная семья по фамилии Франжипани (Красный жасмин). Из далёких странствий по миру хозяин привёз с собой большую обезьяну, которую для забавы держали при дворе. Однажды, возвращаясь домой...* и т. д.

Comment: Формально  двоеточие вводит одно предложение, которое заканчивается после скобки.

Comment: А зачем нам формальность? Это двоеточие разрушает смысл легенды.

Comment: Надо придерживаться структуры предложения.

Comment: Несомненно. Этим и вызван вопрос.